# Multiple actions in asp.net controller api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-apicontroller

Hello People I have 2 methods inside in my controller api:

```
[HttpPost]
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Hotel> Get(HotelSearch hotelSearch)
{
    try
    {
        if (hotelSearch == null)
        {
            hotelSearch = new HotelSearch
            {
                Rooms = new List<RoomSearch> { new RoomSearch { AdultsQuantity = 1, ChildrenQuantity = 0 } },
                Stars = 0,
                City = "MIA",
                IsoCountry = "US",
                DepartureDate = Convert.ToDateTime("10/10/2013"),
                ArrivalDate = Convert.ToDateTime("17/10/2013")
            };
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
    }

    return HotelService.GetHotel(hotelSearch);
}

[HttpPost]
[HttpGet]
public Hotel GetDetails(Hotel hotel)
{
    //return HotelService.GetHotelDetails(hotel);
    return new Hotel();
}
```

Follow my WebApiConfig:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}/",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

When I try to access some method from /api/Hotel/GetDetails/, an message is returned: "Multiple actions were found that match the request".

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Can you show us your routing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should use use separate methods for [HttpPost] and [HttpGet]

Answer (score 0):

You should add Custom route like below

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
             config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
              name: "ApiByName",
              routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{name}",
              defaults: null,
              constraints: new { name = @"^[a-z]+$" }
             );
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "ApiByAction",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
                defaults: new { action = "Get" }
            );
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

        }
```

Hope this helps